# SQL: finding double entries without losing the ID

Tags: sql, join, distinct, max

I have 1 table "Products" that looks like this:

```
ID     Product     Shop   Color
01     Car         A      Black
02     Car         B      Black
03     Bike        C      Red
04     Plane       A      Silver
05     Car         C      Black
06     Bike        A      Red
```

In this example, a Product always has the same color, independent from the Shop where it is sold. 
I want to make a query, that returns a distinct set of products, with the Color property. I also will need to have an ID, it could be any ID, that allows me to do a follow up query.

The result of the query should be:

```
ID     Product     Color
01     Car         Black
03     Bike        Red
04     Plane       Silver
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Product, Color 
FROM 
  Products
```

But that obviously doesn't return the ID as well

I guess I need to join something, but my knowledge of SQL is too poor. I hope this is something simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be one way of getting the result you want:

```
SELECT min(ID), Product, Color FROM table GROUP BY Product, Color;
```

Answer (score 3):

How About

```
SELECT 
   Product, Color, Min(ID)
FROM 
   TABLE
GROUP BY
   Product, Colour
```

That'll return unique Product/Color Combinations and the first (lowest) ID found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause.

The same but obtaining the maximun ID:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, Product, Color
FROM Products
GROUP BY Product, Color
ORDER BY ID
```